# how to implement the db.query code with or clause in where statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=100 OR id=200",null);
```

I want it to convert into

```
db.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy);
```

any idea how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:-

```
String selection = <column name> + "=? OR " + <column name> + "=?";
String []selectionArgs={val1,val2};
```

then apply these in :-

```
db.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy);
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
db.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy);
```

- `table`: `myTable`
- `columns`: Since it's a `SELECT *`, leave as `null` to get all columns.
- `selection`: This is the `WHERE` without the `WHERE`: `id=100 OR id=200`
- `selectionArgs`: This is the `null` in your `rawQuery()`.
- `groupBy`, `having`, `orderBy`: The original query doesn't have these so leave as `null`.

So mechanically wrapping the query to use the `query()` convenience method, it becomes

```
Cursor c = db.query("myTable", null, "id=100 OR id=200", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample class, `db` with a method `rawQuery` that returns you a query after receiving all the required parameters. If this is not what you wanted, let me know. Thanks.

```
class db{

    private String query;

    static String rawQuery (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){

        this.query = "SELECT " + getColumns(columns) +
                    " FROM " + dbColumn + 
                    " WHERE " getSelectionArgs(selectionArgs) +
                    " GROUP BY " + groupBy +
                    " HAVING " + having +
                    " ORDER BY " + orderBy +
                    "; ";
        return query;

    }
    private String getColumns(String[] arr){
        String cols = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            cols += arr[i] + ", ";
        }
        cols += arr[arr.length-1];

        return cols;
    }

    private String getSelectionArgs(String[] arr){
        String args = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            args += arr[i] + ", ";
        }
        args += arr[arr.length-1];

        return args;
    }

}
```